# How To Create Different Flavor Of Build with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I wants to build my anndroid project with maven.

There are 3 projects

---

Project - A (jar file )

Project - B (jar file )

Project - C (sdk package)

---

Project **C** is depended on **B**

Project **B** is depended on **A**

With maven I wants to release two flavor of by build

**1st flavor :** Release JAR from **B** (which contain code from B & A)

**2nd flavor :** Release SDK from **C**  (which contain code from C & B & A)

Can I control this behaviors from MAVEN.

Comment: Have a look at maven profiles. This could be what you need.

Comment: Do you want both to be the result of one build, or do you want to choose which one to build?

Comment: A JAR does not contain classes/code from other project so you are talking about a jar-with-dependencies  (fatjar / ueberjar)...

Answer (score 1):

For the **"1st flavor"**, you can use the `maven-assembly-plugin` with the predefined `desriptor` `jar-with-dependencies` that will embed all the dependencies into your project's jar, but pay attention to the transitive dependencies that could be embedded into it also. Otherwise you can also use the `maven-shade-plugin` which is having options that you could be interested in like `minimizeJar` and an easier way to configure of includes and excludes ([see doc here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)).

For the **"2nd flavor"**, the use of the `maven-assembly-plugin` would fit well with its `bin` `descriptor` or by defining your own descriptor if you need to include other files ([see the descriptor format here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html)). You can find a few examples on how to configure and use the `maven-assembly-plugin` for that on SO (you can also look at the questions I already answered about this plugin)